# How to add a finger print registration service to my system

Tags: c#, fingerprint, biometrics

I am creating a system for a private medical center(just to improve myself) i am creating the system using C#

i am finished with the system but i want to add a fingerprint  scanner to register the patients so there information can be accessed by scanning the finger

I don't have a scanner yet but i would like to try that out using a simulation

My questions are

1) What is the output type of the fingerprint scanner(String ,  byte[] , long)
2) Is there a way i can artificially create simulation prints and then use it to test the system

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: generally output of the fingerprint scanner is byte[] , but depending on the biometric SDK that can differ.

Answer 2: Yes you can artificially create simulation prints and test.

I recommend [bio-plugin](http://www.m2sys.com/bioplugin/) biometric sdk rather than using low level sdks. Also it supports fingerprint, finger vein, palm vein modalities.